# Linear Regression ValueError X shape Y shape with .values() numpy.array. OK, ValueError Expected 2D array, got 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, linear-regression

**PROBLEM**

Preparing data for LinearRegression with pre-encoded dataset, e.g., null, NAN, imputed missing values handles. Problem with ValueError on numpy.array even after trying .reshape(). This attempt is trying to fix this code which ran 5 years ago.

Assigning Y response SalePrice column to numpy.array with .values
Assigning X features (all others)

Shape looks good:

X shape: (1460, 250)
Y shape: (1460,)

Even after I reshape, ValueError is raised:
X shape: (365000, 1)
X shape: (1460, 1)

**ERROR**

```
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0.24107763 0.20358284 0.26190807 ... 0.321622   0.14890293 0.15636717].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

**CODE**

```
train_data = pd.read_csv("../data/train_data_encoded.csv")
test_data = pd.read_csv("../data/test_data_encoded.csv")

train_data.loc[train_data['LotFrontage'].isnull(), 'LotFrontage'] = 0.0
train_data.drop(['Id'], axis=1)

Y = train_data['SalePrice'].values
X = train_data.values
print('X shape:', X.shape)
print('Y shape:', Y.shape)

X_reshaped = X.reshape(-1, 1)
print('X shape:', X_reshaped.shape)

Y_reshaped = Y.reshape(-1, 1)
print('X shape:', Y_reshaped.shape)

lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X, Y)
res = lm.predict(Y)
```

**Environment Console**
[image: Python Environment Console Variables]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. need inplace=True

   ```
   train_data.drop(['Id'], axis=1, inplace=True)
   ```
2. Why didn't you remove 'SalePrice' columns in X?

   ```
    Y = train_data['SalePrice'].values
    X = train_data.values
   ```

you can use, its work for me, share my code:

```
    X = df[['Area', 'Status', 'Project', 'Region']]
    y = df[['Price_G']]

    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = .20, 
random_state = 40)

    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    predicted = regr.predict(X_test)
```